# apply changes to running instance of a class from another class

Tags: python, class, methods, call

Some weeks ago I had to simplify a program drastically, because I couldn't find a solution for this probably simple problem.
Now I'm stuck at the same issue again and hope somebody can help me to fix it.

I'm using PyQt5 and started a `QWidget` out of my main class `Class_One`, from which I opened a second class `Class_Two` with the following lines.

```
def on_create_search(self):
    self.search_form = Class_Two()
    self.search_form.show()
```

In `Class_Two` I save changes to a JSON file, which should also effect a dictionary and a visible `QTreeWidget` from `Class_One`.

So what I want to do is, to execute a method in `Class_One`, triggered by `Class_Two`, just as it was called from the running instance of `Class_One`.
The called method should read in the JSON file and apply the changes to the data and the GUI of the running instance of `Class_One`.

Calling such a method from another instance of `Class_One` didn't help me out, because the changes have to be applied to my running class instance of `Class_One`.
Perhaps there is an even better way, so I'm open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback.

```py
class Class_One:
    def callback(self, arg1, arg2):
        # code you want

    def on_create_search(self):
        self.search_form = Class_Two()
        self.search_form.show(self.callback)

class Class_two:
    def show(self, callback):
        # original code
        callback(arg1, arg2)
```